# Equivalent condition for the existence of a $t∈(T_0,T_1]$ with $|f(t)-\lim_{s→t-}f(s)|>ε$ for a right-continuous function $f$ with left limits

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, continuity

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be right-continuous and assume that the left-sided limit $$f(t-):=\lim_{s\to t-}f(s)$$ exists for all $t\ge0$. Now, let $$\Delta f(t):=f(t)-f(t-)\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0,$$ $0\le T_0<T_1<T_1$ and $\varepsilon\ge0$.

> How can we show that
>
> 1. $\exists t\in(T_0,T_1]:|\Delta f(t)|>\varepsilon$
> 2. $\exists k\in\mathbb N:\forall l\in\mathbb N:\exists s_1,s_2\in\mathbb Q\cap\left(T_0,T_1+\frac1l\right]:|s_1-s_2|<\frac1l\text{ and }|f(s_1)-f(s_2)|>\varepsilon+\frac1k$
>
> are equivalent?

While intuitively reasonable, it's not clear to me how we need to construct the equivalence. For example, assume 1.: Since $f$ has a left-sided limit at $t$, we can minimize $|f(s)-f(t-)|$ arbitrarily by choosing $s<t$ sufficiently close to $t$. In the same way, by right-continuity at $t$, we can minimize $|f(s)-f(t)|$ arbitrarily by choosing $s\ge t$ sufficiently close to $t$. So, maybe the basic idea could be to choose $s_1<t$ and $s_2\ge t$ and use $$\varepsilon<|\Delta f(t)|\le|f(s_1)-f(s_2)|+|f(s_1)-f(t-)|+|f(s_2)-f(t)|\tag1.$$ (I've assumed $\varepsilon>0$. Guess the case $\varepsilon=0$ needs to be treated separately?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. implies 2.:

As $|\Delta f(t)| > \epsilon$ we can choose $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|\Delta f(t)| \geq \epsilon+3/k$. Since $f$ has a finite left-hand limit at $t$, we can choose $\delta_1>0$ such that

$$|f(u)-f(t-)| < \frac{1}{k} \quad \text{for all $u \in [t-\delta_1,t)$}.$$

Analogously, the right-continuity yields that there exists $\delta_2>0$ such that

$$|f(t)-f(v)| < \frac{1}{k} \quad \text{for all $v \in [t,t+\delta_2]$}.$$

If $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$ is a given fixed number we may assume without loss of generality that $\delta := \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\} <1/(2\ell)$. Choose some $s_1 \in [t-\delta,t) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $s_2 \in [t,t+\delta) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. Then $$|s_1-s_2| \leq |s_1-t| + |t-s_2| \leq 2 \delta = \frac{1}{\ell}$$ and $$\begin{align*} \epsilon + \frac{3}{k} \leq |\Delta f(t)| &\leq |f(s_1)-f(t-)| + |f(t)-f(s_2)| + |f(s_1)-f(s_2)| \\ &< \frac{2}{k} + |f(s_1)-f(s_2)|, \end{align*}$$ i.e. $$|f(s_1)-f(s_2)| > \epsilon + \frac{1}{k} $$

> 2. implies 1.

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ be as in 2. and choose for any $\ell \in \mathbb{N}$ some numbers $s_1^{(\ell)}$ and $s_2^{(\ell)}$ in $[T_0,T_1+1]$ such that $$|s_1^{(\ell)}-s_2^{(\ell)}| \leq 1/\ell \tag{1}$$ and $$|f(s_1^{(\ell)})-f(s_2^{(\ell)})| > \epsilon+1/k. \tag{2}$$ Since the interval $[T_0,T_1+1]$ is compact we can find convergent subsequences, say $(t_1^{(\ell)})$ and $(t_2^{(\ell)})$,  of $(s_1^{(\ell)})$ and $(s_2^{(\ell)})$, and it follows from $(1)$ that $$ t = \lim_{\ell \to \infty} t_1^{(\ell)} = \lim_{t \to \infty} t_2^{(\ell)}.$$ By the continuity assumptions on $f$, this implies

$$f_i := \lim_{\ell \to \infty} f(t_i^{(\ell)}) \in \{f(t),f(t-)\} \tag{3}$$

for $i=1,2$. On the other hand, we know from $(2)$ that

$$|f_1-f_2|> \epsilon + \frac{1}{k}>0, \tag{4}$$

and therefore $f_1 \neq f_2$. From $(3)$ we thus conclude that  one of the limits equals $f(t)$ and th other limit equals $f(t-)$. Hence, by (4),

$$|\Delta f(t)|= |f(t)-f(t-)| > \epsilon.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've got a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3025905/steps-of-a-markov-chain-subordinated-to-a-poisson-process) (even so it might not look related at a first glance). Would be great if you could help there too. Oh, and I don't know if you noticed, [I've asked a (somehow related) question on the convergence of discrete-time Markov chain to Feller processes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019020/convergence-of-discrete-time-markov-chain-to-feller-processes). I could imagine that you have at least an idea for an answer.

Comment: If $g:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and $$\sigma:=\inf\left\{t\ge0:|f(t)|\ge\varepsilon\right\},$$ then $|g(\sigma)|=\varepsilon$. Are we able to say something similar about $|\Delta f(\tau)|$ and $f(\tau)$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Unless you tell me something about the relation of $f$, $g$ and $\sigma$, $\tau$ this is impossible to say...

Comment: Sorry, $$\tau:=\inf\left\{t\ge0:|\Delta f(t)|>\varepsilon\right\}.$$

Comment: @0xbadf00d No, there are no such statements... $|\Delta f(\tau)|$ might take any value $>\epsilon$.

Comment: That's unfortunate. As you may guess, I'm still trying to figure out why the (supposed to be simple) claim in first link I've posted above holds.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I don't have enough time to answer all of your questions ... perhaps I'll take a look at them at the weekend.

Comment: Thank you. Thinking about a Poisson process, shouldn't we be able to conclude $f(\tau)=1$, if $f(0)=0$, $f([0,\infty))\subseteq\mathbb N_0$ and $\Delta f([0,\infty))\subseteq\left\{0,1\right\}$? What's worrying me is whether $f(\tau)$ is the value immediately before or after the jump.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Note that a Poisson process has only finitely many jumps in finite time intervals, and therefore $\tau=T_1$ is the first time the process jumps (i.e. the infimum is attained at $t=T_1$). In particular $f(\tau)=1$.